# How to calculate the mulitiple Contingency Tables from a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, contingency

I have a dataframe (df) as given below

```
Hair  Legs  Type
 0     0      1
 0     0      1
 1     2      1
 1     2      1
 1     4      1
 0     2      2
 0     2      2
 1     6      6
```

and I want to calculate contingency tables for all the different combinations. For example, a contingency table for Hair(H=1), Legs (L=2) and Type (T=1) would look like this

```
        | T  |  T` |
--------------------
(H,2L)  | 2  |  0  |
--------------------
(H,2L)` | 3  |  3  |
```

I am currently doing the same with other variables and it is doing quite well however those variables are boolean and I am facing with this problem with only the variable (Legs) which has numerical values (0,2,4,5,6,8). 
Moreover, I want to calculate for H=0, L=0, T=0 and then for H=1, L=4 and T=1 and so on.
Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.